# Get specific data from MYSQL using PHP

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as follows
**user table**

| user_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | zia |
| 2 | john |
| 3 | raza |

**subject table**

| data_id | user_id | subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Math |
| 2 | 1 | Chem |
| 3 | 1 | Bio |
| 4 | 2 | Math |
| 5 | 2 | Phy |

when I am querying data i am getting results like this:

```
 [
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "name": "zia",
    "subject": [
        "Math",
        "Chem",
        "Bio"
    ]
},
{
    "user_id": "2",
    "name": "john",
    "subject": [
        "Math",
        "Phy"
    ]
},
```

]

*My query is as follows*

```
SELECT
users.user_id,
users.name,
GROUP_CONCAT(subjects.subject) sub
FROM
  `users`
  INNER JOIN subjects ON users.user_id = subjects.user_id
  GROUP BY
  subjects.user_id;
```

*but actually I want to get data in following way:*

the resuluts shown above are in such a way that  if an entry from user table does not have coresponding enteries in subject table even then  we must have user name and user id in our rsults as follows

```
 [
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "name": "zia",
    "subject": [
        "Math",
        "Chem",
        "Bio"
    ]
},
{
    "user_id": "2",
    "name": "john",
    "subject": [
        "Math",
        "Phy"
    ]
},
{
    "user_id": "3",
    "name": "Raza",
    
}
```

]

Here as you see that we have data in such a way that all the enteries from user table are shown alog with subject enteries from subject table if they match otherwise every user table entery is showing up with no affect.

*PLease help me in solving this issue **

Comment: You probably need to use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, because you want to retrieve user without subject too

Comment: I will post it as solution

Comment: Here is the demo-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65d80c/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, because you want to retrieve user without subject too